# Filter categories/tags to display in multiple metaboxes for selection in back-end

Tags: categories, metabox, tags

My site uses a lot of categories and tags for author selection in the back-end. To make it more user friendly for authors I need to arrange the categories and post tags in numerous metaboxes for selection on the post edit screen. I would like to display some selected categories and their children in one metabox for author selection while other categories will go into a second and third metabox and so on. The same should apply to the tags. Can anyone point me in the right direction how to accomplish such a customization? Can I register new taxonomies which will include categories/tags based on their ID's and create new metaboxes displaying only those ID's?

The Wordpress default metaboxes for categories and tags display all categories in one box.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup! Just register a new taxonomy in your functions.php and it'll show up in your post editor.

```
function my_custom_taxonomy(){
  $args = array(
   'settings' => 'here'
   );

   register_taxonomy('Authors', 'post', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'my_custom_taxonomy');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy